# Attempting to host a website through LAN with WAMP

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I am attempting to access a website through a computer that is hosted on another computer on the same wifi network. The host has Windows 10. All WAMP services are turned on, the site is in the www directory with a site name of `index.php`, and I have allowed access by changing `httpd.conf` and `httpd-vhosts.conf` as per youtube tutorials:

httpd.conf changes:

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80
Listen HostsIPAddress:80 ----------- (added this line)
...
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted ------------ (changed from denied to granted)
</Directory>
...
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all granted ------------ (changed from denied to granted)
</Files>
...
<Directory "${SRVROOT}/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted ------------ (changed from denied to granted)
</Directory>
```

httpd-vhosts.conf changes:

```
<Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted ------------ (changed from denied to granted)
  </Directory>
```

but when I type in HostsIPAddress:80 on other devices' browsers (all devices use chrome), the connection times out. I can access the site with localhost:80 on the host computer, getting the site on another computer is where the issue is.